# Add Product button unavailable in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

As today Magento 2.0 was released, I installed it and was exploring its admin panel. I am unable to find Add Product button on Catalog page, can someone please guide me if I am on the wrong page?

[image: Magento 2.0 Catalog]

Comment: Bump, did you get a solution for this ?

Comment: @Harit No, I am still struggling...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

That was the bug in old version of magento community 2.0.

Download and reinstall again and it will work for you.